# How to do server rendering with react-router 1.0.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new in React and following a tutorial to build an isomorphic app. In the server side it use `router.run()` do the rendering thing, but it's removed in react-router 1.0.0.

```
Router.run(routes, req.url, Handler => {
    let content = React.renderToString(<Handler />);
    res.render('index', {
        content: content
    });
});
```

What the *Update Guide* said is

```
// v0.13.x
Router.run(routes, (Handler) => {
  render(<Handler/>, el);
})

// v1.0
render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, el)
```

But how can I do with the server rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```jsx
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { match, RoutingContext } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'

serve((req, res) => {
  // Note that req.url here should be the full URL path from
  // the original request, including the query string.
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
      res.status(200).send(renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />))
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  })
})
```

More can be found [in the docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md).

Comment: Thx. But when I run these codes, the shell report an error about: `renderToString(<RoutingContext`, `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. How could I fix this?